# QGIS3 entry constraints enforce not null constraint but allow zero as value

Tags: constraints, qgis

I am preparing a QGIS project for fieldwork in QField. In the geopackage database for data entry I have an integer column with the count of a species. I have set the constraints to "Not null" and "enforce not null constraint" to avoid incomplete observations to be entered. That works well for positive observations. However, it is not possible to enter 0 as observation.

How can I keep the restrictions to avoid incomplete data but allow explicit zero counts to be entered?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Layer Properties` of your layer go to the desired field/column and add the expression under `Constraints`:

```
"your_field_name" >= 0
```

Mind the double quotes. Also be sure your widget type is `Range` and `Minimum` is set to `0`.